# MSBuild Logging

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am relatively new to tfs. I am creating msbuild logfiles during a build, but they are not getting moved to the drop location.

I am attempting to move a teambuild from 2010 to 2013. Due to versioned namespaces, I recreated the workflow template from a fresh default from the tfs server. The build is successful and the binaries are placed in the drop location via custom activity.

MSBuild is used four times on the workflow. Each has a unique LogFile name and use the same LogFileDropLocation. I get the binaries without the logfiles in the drop location. Using a diagnostic build, I do see that LogFileDropLocation has the correct drop location. However, my log files remain on the agent and do not get moved to the drop.

In the 2010 build, I get binaries and four logfiles in the drop location.

My question is, should Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.MSBuild handle the copy/move of the log files, as I suspect, or later in the workflow? MSDN and the several books I have don't actually discuss how msbuild handles the logging. I am hoping someone knows specifically how MSBuild handles the logfile.

Comment: You should avoid customising the workflow. The new build system in 2015 and VSO does not use workflow. You should customise using PowerShell..

Comment: Ouch, thank you. This is a legacy build moving to 2013. Quite a bit of rewrite in the pipe :-)

Comment: The MSBuild Activity takes in the LogFileDropLocation as a parameter. Would anyone happen to know how Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Workflow.Activities.MSBuild activity and the overall workflow handles these log files and use the log file drop location value?

Comment: That's output not code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the XML files in your project and mark them as Content. They will be copied to the bin folder as output.

Example: Create a new project in visual studio. Them create an empty .xml file in the root of the project under source control. Right click and mark it as Content. Build the project.

You should see the bin folder has been created and the .xml file has been copied to that location.

This output is considered "compiled" or "generated" even though it is a copy. You may want to do some build processing to add parameters later.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the MSBuild utility you can add parameters and have MSBuild handle the log file the way you want. I don't know the TFS workflow you've described so see how you could add that there.

You command can look something like this:

```
MSBuild.exe /target:Build Solution.sln /filelogger /fileloggerparameters:LogFile=C:\path\to\file\build.log;Verbosity=normal
```

Loggers are explained here (under Switches for Loggers): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx
Verbosity is explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.loggerverbosity.aspx